# Media print not taking up the styles

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, media-queries

I am using `HTML-to-paper` plugin for printing my content on printer, but the issue I am facing is it is not taking any style I am defining on `@media print`

**Issues I am facing**

- Initially I am hiding one of my column and also want that not to print on print but that is printing
- On print I want to remove input fields from table but it is not doing that also

Basically it is not taking any styling I am giving on @media print

**Pluging use**

In main.js I am doing this

```
    import VueHtmlToPaper from "vue-html-to-paper";


    const options = {
      name: '_blank',
      specs: [
        'fullscreen=yes',
        'titlebar=yes',
        'scrollbars=yes'
      ],
      styles: [
        'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'https://unpkg.com/kidlat-css/css/kidlat.css'
      ]
    }
Vue.use(VueHtmlToPaper,options);
```

I don't know why this plugin is not taking the css on media print

[This is the plugin Github](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html-to-paper).

[This is the working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cori-jl92i).

I just want to know why this plugin is not supporting media print, or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to provide you code snippet thats is having problem. If you are sure you that you have defined css correctly.Then probably your `@media print` style couldnot override, which happened with me. So better add `!important` to style properties for `@media`.

Comment: @The_ehT I have given link of `Code Sandbox` of mine please check, and important I have use but it is also not working

Comment: sorry. I'm checking

Comment: @The_ehT have you found the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `@media print` css query is not working because `VueHtmlToPaper` is using `window.open` API to open a new window with options given. And in your option I can see two stylesheets currently

```
styles: [
    'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'https://unpkg.com/kidlat-css/css/kidlat.css'
  ]
```

Hence your media print style

```
@media print {
  input {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

will not work as it doesnot exist in the new window.

To include your style one way is to host your `@media print` styles as separate `.css` file and then add it to styles option

```
styles: [
    'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'https://unpkg.com/kidlat-css/css/kidlat.css',
    'https://myhostip/css/print.css'// like this
  ]
```

Comment: how can I host a new file, I can create new .css file in my project folder.

Comment: For testing you can add .css file to dist folder and add `'http://your-vue-local-host:port-no/path-to-.css'`

Comment: this will not help as while going for production it can cause issue, Is there any other option?

Comment: For production you can use real url to your .css file

Comment: No it is not taking style by putting my localhost url,I have created.css file and  doing like this ` 'http:localhost:8086/../src/assets/style.css'` but still no output as required

Comment: its not the correct path. First open .html file and see the path of existing .css file.

Comment: I didn't get you, I don't have any .html file all I have is .vue files

Comment: .vue files are just templating files. They are not served in browsers.

Comment: I am totally confused now, I know they are templet file, how can I set path if the above one is wrong

Comment: It will be difficult to explain everything. I would suggest you to try locally build a sample vue project and then serve it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve  npm package to know how it works. When it runs, open the console and see from where .css and .js files are being served.